# Having problem in displaying product details on different pages using django postgresql

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am working on a website and am facing a problem.I have a page category.html which is working fine.Below is its code(used for loop)

```
                      <div class="product-caption">
                              <h4><a href="#" id="{{product.productid}}">{{product.name}}</a></h4>
                                <div class="price">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>RS {{product.currentprice}}</li>
                                        <li class="discount">RS {{product.originalprice}}</li>
                                        <div>
                                        <a href="/category/singleproduct/" class="btn header-btn btn-outline-info">View</a>
                                        <a href="#" class="btn header-btn btn-outline-info">Add to Cart</a>
                                    </div>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

and in this when i click on view it transfers me to /category/singleproduct. Below is some part of the code for singleproduct.html:

```
            <div class="single_product_img">
          <img src="{{product.disimage.url}}" alt="#" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
      <div class="single_product_text text-center">
        <h3>{{product.name}} <br>rebound pillows</h3>
```

But this is giving me nothing.I want this to display the image and name of the product that was selected(using view in category.html)

Here is my views.py:

```
def category(request):
    types = Category.objects.all()
    prods= Product.objects.all()
    return render(request,"category.html",{'types':types,'prods':prods})


def singleproduct(request):
    types = Category.objects.all()
    prods= Product.objects.all()
    return render(request,"singleproduct.html", {'types':types,'prods':prods})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you aren't passing any info to the `singleproduct` view. I would suggest passing the product ID to `singleproduct` via the url:

`<a href="/category/singleproduct/{{product.productid}}" class="btn header-btn btn-outline-info">View</a>`

You can then modify your `singleproduct` view:

```
def singleproduct(request, id):
    types = Category.objects.all()
    prods= Product.objects.filter(productid = id)
    return render(request,"singleproduct.html", {'types':types,'prods':prods})
```

Which will grab just the one product that you're looking for and pass it to the template.

You'll have to modify your `urls.py` for `singleproduct` to something like this:

`path('category/singleproduct/<int:id>', views.singleproduct, name='singleproduct')`

In order to facilitate passing information through the url.

Comment: What additions do i have to make in singleproduct.html so that it fetches the data of the object viewed and displays the name and image of the product.With my current code it is not displaying the image and name (i am not using any jinja or python code in singlecategory html page)

Comment: I used your code . There are no errors but the image and name of that product is not being displayed –

Comment: Are products being displayed in your `category.html`? If so you can use the same code you used to display items in `category.html`. The code I provided is not going to be perfect for your application, just an example how how it can be done. I would make sure that an ID is correctly being passed to the view, and that a product is being returned from `prods= Product.objects.filter(productid = id)`. If not, is the url pattern correct? Is `productid` not a valid field of the `Product` object?

Comment: Yes the products are being displayed in category.html...The products have view button under them which on being clicked opens category/singleproduct . In that singeproduct.html I want to display the image and name of the product for which view was clicked but nothing is being displayed...Do i need to use for loop in singleproduct.html too ? If so then how

Comment: Yes, all queries in django will return a `QeurySet` which needs to be iterated over. You would do something such as ```{% for product in prods%} <h1>{{product.name}}</h1>{% endfor %}```

Comment: Ok thanks.I will try it and revert in sometime. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hey there!! I know its been long but i wanted to know about how does your solution work?I mean to say where does this product id refer to or in urls when we mention <int:id> does that id is referring to somewhere.Can you please explain how this is working